# Thunderbird does not update imap folders anymore

Tags: thunderbird, imap, refresh

How can you tell Thunderbird to reload the imap folder list?

I would assume, that any email client would refresh the imap folders every time mails are fetched, since it cannot know which folders contain new mails. Since this does not work with the current Thunderbird version, I am looking for alternative ways to fetch the imap folder structure. It is important, because if thunderbird does not show these, I will miss the emails in those folders and not even notice anything went wrong.

Note: Before the update to 115.0.1, I could just restart Thunderbird or close/reopen the parent folder and thunderbird would refresh the folder list. Maybe they introduced a bug, so it does not refresh anymore. Since both ways stopped working, I am looking for alternatives.
Are there other ways to reload the folder list from imap with the Thunderbird 115.0.1?

Comment: Sounds like one of your folders (probably the inbox) database is corrupted. You can right-click a folder, properties, repair button to fix it. Alternatively, right-click the account, properties, and then set which folders to download when syncing there.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks, I tried this now for both the Inbox and the parent folder of the folder that's now showing up. Sadly, this did not fix it for me.

Comment: Since its now showing up, what happens if you manually send/receive?

Comment: @LPChip: Naturally, I had tried that, but it did nor help either.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird released a new version, which fixed this bug.

Using Thunderbird 115.1.0, the folders should update again.